# Xilinx Max Frequency of an instance

Tags: fpga, timing

I have a VHDL design, my top file has two instances (i.e., Master and Slave) that are clocked using two outputs of a DCM instance (i.e., clk_0 and clk_2x respectively). One of the things I am interested in is to check the maximum clock frequency achievable for the instance called Slave. So, after PAR I have opened the static timing report generated by Xilinx ISE but I am not sure how to find this information. In fact, I have the feeling that the Max. Frequency reported for clk_2x is independent of the final destination (e.g., of the LUT depth of Slave in this example). Anyone can help me with this question?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Since PAR will only invest enough effort to meet your timing constraints the static timing report does not tell you anything about the max. possible frequency. Only when timing errors begin to apear one can assume that the implementation is moving closer to the max. frequency, but the timing errors could have different causes. The max. frequency estimate reported after synthesis is a good rule of thumb of what frequency is possible.

Comment: Thanks @damage, I was not considering the synthesis results as some people say that those values are a bad estimation.

Comment: Well the max. frequency given after synthesis is a rough estimate, but it's better than a wild guess. To see how close to reality it is you can try to constrain your clock to the max. frequency given by the synthesis report. Results will vary depending on factors like device utilization, MAP and PAR options &cetera.